# How can you get grunt to run automatically each day?

Tags: cron, gruntjs, protractor

I'd like to run my protractor end-to-end tests automatically each day.

Currently I can do

```
$ grunt
```

In the test directory and they run.

Is there a way to get them to run automatically each day at a specific time?

I've tried using cron, but according to [this](http://www.themechanism.com/voice/2012/08/28/getting-node-js-and-cron-to-play-nicely/), I'd have to make all of my require paths into absolute paths, which I don't want to do.

Comment: You should specify your OS. What about using a CI server ?

Comment: A CI server sounds like overkill, I just want to be able to run the tests periodically.

Comment: May be you could give a try to [launchctl](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Darwin/Reference/ManPages/man1/launchctl.1.html)

Comment: I don't think CI is overkill, If you happen to be on Github it's pretty easy with TravisCI. cron is fine if you're running locally, but seems kinda hacky.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use a node script and `setInterval`:

```
var exec = require('child_process').exec
var path = require('path')
var running = false

var run = function(what, where) {
  if (running === true) return
  running = true

  // by default, just run grunt
  what = what || 'grunt'
  // by default, run on grunt in the current working directory
  where = path.resolve(where || path.join(process.cwd(), 'Gruntfile.coffee'))

  what += ' --gruntfile=' + where
  exec(what, { cwd: path.dirname(where) }, function(err, stdout, stderr) {
    if (err || stderr) { /* log the error somewhere */ }
    /* log the stdout if needed*/
    console.log(stdout)
    running = false
  })
}

setInterval(function() {
  run(/* set what to run, where to run */)
  /* or even multiple gruntfiles and node projects */
}, 24 * 60 * 60 * 1000) // once a day
```

This is platform agnostic, easy to start and stop, easy to maintain and customize.

Check out a library like https://www.npmjs.org/package/forever for running a node script forever. Or many of the other ways: nohup, monit, upstart, etc.

Answer (score 1):

Using Kyle Robinson Young's answer along with the node module [cron](https://www.npmjs.org/package/cron), I came up with the following which runs the gruntfile every day at 5:00pm:

```
var cronJob = require('cron').CronJob
  , exec = require('child_process').exec
  , path = require('path')
  , running = false
  ;

var run = function(what, where) {
  if (running === true) {
    return;
  }
  running = true;

  // by default, just run grunt
  what = what || 'grunt';
  // by default, run on grunt in the current working directory
  where = path.resolve(where || path.join(process.cwd(), 'Gruntfile.js'));

  what += ' --gruntfile=' + where;

  exec(what, { cwd: path.dirname(where) }, function(err, stdout, stderr) {
    if (err || stderr) {
      console.log(err);
    }
    /* log the stdout if needed*/
    console.log(stdout);
    running = false;
  });
};

new cronJob('00 00 17 * * *', function(){
    console.log('Running Gruntfile ' + new Date());
    var what = 'grunt'
      , where
      ;

    run(what, where);
}, null, true);
```